# Formatting a decimal with java.text.DecimalFormat

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

I'm trying to format the number `0.14000` using `java.text.DecimalFormat` in order to obtain the value `0.14`. Using the format `#.##` I get `140`. What's wrong?

Comment: It's working differently on my system and prints `0,14`... What is your system's locale? Maybe, exchanging the dot in the pattern by a comma would suffice.

Comment: In your example, try feeding it the number 1.14 and see what comes out. The reason why 0.14 is returning .14 is that it ignores the zero on the left. It considers it being literally of no value.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Example:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MyDecimalFormat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println( decimalFormat.format( 0.14000 ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

> 0.14